# Understanding recursive loop that returns an inverted count

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
inner conditional: 5
inner conditional: 4
inner conditional: 3
inner conditional: 2
inner conditional: 1
0
```

The function that created the above output is below and I perfectly understand how it works.

```
function loop(counter){

    if(counter > 0){
        console.log("inner conditional: " + counter );
        return loop(counter - 1)
    }

    console.log(counter);
    return counter
}

loop(5)
```

---

When the function is modified so that the inner condition does not return the function the console.log displays the following.

```
inner conditional: 5
inner conditional: 4
inner conditional: 3
inner conditional: 2
inner conditional: 1
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Below is the function that is responsible for the above output.

```
function loop(counter){

    if(counter > 0){
        console.log("inner conditional: " + counter );
        loop(counter - 1)
    }

    console.log(counter);
    return counter
}

loop(5)
```

I do not understand this at all. I would simply like an explanation as to what is happening to create the extended forward count.

I used the following tool to visualize stepping through the code and I still don't "get" it:  http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=display

Comment: Simply, removing the `return`, when it ends the call to `loop(counter-1)` it continues to the last `console.log`, even if counter is `> 0`...you can turn things using an `else console.log(counter);`

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. I want an explanation to why the count counts forward five times. If you use the code execution tool I linked to , I want an explanation for what is happening after step 20

Comment: well, it's exactly what my comment was about, but maybe I explained it badly: calling the `loop(counter-1)` recursively, and being the `console.log` after the call, means that it will `log` starting from the most inner (last) call, and comung up printing from the oldest function calls when the inner are completed...sorry for not being precise, hope it helps

Comment: In your first snippet when counter is greater than 0 it returns before reaching to the `console.log(counter);` instruction. However in the second snippet there is no return before the `console.log(counter);` instruction so it reaches to console.log every time before returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I was looking for is that the 1-5 count is being pulled off the top of the stack.

I found a great youtube video that explains this here with visualizations:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8JpA5MjYac

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you call the function again and the function ends with a counter < 1, but it has not end the actual function itself and make the output with the counter later.

The same level if indentation shows the same function.

```
inner conditional: 5
    inner conditional: 4
        inner conditional: 3
            inner conditional: 2
                inner conditional: 1
                    0
                1
            2
        3
    4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

From inside the first instance of the loop function you are calling the loop function with a return, that prevents rest of the statements after "return" to execute.
However, in the second instance loop function is called without the return, hence the console.log outside the if condition is also executed and you see both the console.log outputs.